# string iterator + offset out of range

Tags: c++, graph, iterator

What is the cause of this error? I can't figure out where it's coming from. The code compiles and runs, but after it says that the file is loaded, it freaks out. Running through it in a debugger does no good, it doesn't find any errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/metis.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list_traits<
vecS, vecS, undirectedS, listS> GraphTraits;
// type 'Vertex' identifies each vertex uniquely:
typedef GraphTraits::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
// Property type associated to each vertex:
struct VertexProperty {
string name;  // Name of vertex (i.e., "location")
Vertex predecessor; // Predecessor along optimal path.
double distance; // Distance to the goal, along shortest path.
default_color_type color; // for use by dijkstra.
VertexProperty(const string& aName = "") : name(aName) { };
};
// Property type associated to each edge:
struct EdgeProperty {
double weight; // distance to travel along this edge.
EdgeProperty(double aWeight = 0.0) : weight(aWeight) { };
};
// Type of the graph used:
typedef adjacency_list<
vecS, // out-edges stored in vector 
vecS, // vertices stored in vector
undirectedS, // undirected graph (edge don't have a specific direction)
VertexProperty, // properties associated to each vertex.
EdgeProperty // properties associated to each edge.
> Graph;
// Create a global graph object 'g'
Graph g;
// This is a visitor for the dijkstra algorithm. This visitor does nothing special.
struct do_nothing_dijkstra_visitor {
template <typename Vertex, typename Graph>
void initialize_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) const { };
template <typename Vertex, typename Graph>
void examine_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) const { };
template <typename Edge, typename Graph>
void examine_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) const { };
template <typename Vertex, typename Graph>
void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) const { };
template <typename Edge, typename Graph>
void edge_relaxed(Edge e, const Graph& g) const { };
template <typename Edge, typename Graph>
void edge_not_relaxed(Edge e, const Graph& g) const { };
template <typename Vertex, typename Graph>
void finish_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) const { };
};
int main() {
string tempName1;
string tempName2;
string tempString;
string data2;
double weight;
cout << "please enter the data file name: ";
char strFileName[256];
cin >> strFileName;
// preparing the data
ifstream fin;
fin.open(strFileName);
if (!fin) {
    cerr << "Can't open data file, leaving...\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
else{
    cout << "file loaded." << endl << endl;
}
// Create a map to associate names to vertices of the graph:
map<string, Vertex> name2v;
getline(fin, tempString); //Vertices:
getline(fin, tempString); //Location1, Location2, ...
stringstream tempSS(tempString);
while (getline(tempSS, tempName1, ',')) {
    // Add vertex to graph, with name 'tempName1' and 
    //  record the associated Vertex in the name2v map:
    name2v[tempName1] = add_vertex(VertexProperty(tempName1), g);
}
getline(fin, tempString); //Edges:
while (getline(fin, tempString)){ // (Location1, Location2, 6)
    //remove parentheses
    tempString.erase(tempString.begin(), tempString.begin() +  
 tempString.find('(') + 1);
    tempString.erase(tempString.begin() + tempString.find(')'), 
 tempString.end());
    stringstream temp_ss(tempString);
    getline(temp_ss, tempName1, ',');
    getline(temp_ss, tempName2, ',');
    temp_ss >> weight;
    // Add edge to graph, by finding vertices associated 
    //  to tempName1 and tempName2:
    add_edge(name2v[tempName1], name2v[tempName2], EdgeProperty(weight), g);
}
char x;
Vertex current_vertex;
Vertex start_vertex;
Vertex goal_vertex;
cout << endl << "How would you like to process your data file?" << endl;
cout << "1.) shortest path" << endl;
cout << "2.) minimum spanning tree" << endl;
cout << "3.) Travelling Salesman" << endl << endl;
returnQuestion:
cout << "please enter 1,2,3 or Q to quit: ";
cin >> x;
switch (x){
case '1': //do the work for shortest path
    cout << endl << "please enter the location name to start from: ";
    cin >> tempName1;
    cout << endl << "please enter the location name for the destination: ";
    cin >> tempName2;
    // Retrieve the vertices for the start and goal:
    start_vertex = name2v[tempName1];
    goal_vertex = name2v[tempName2];
    cout << g[name2v[tempName1]].name << g[name2v[tempName2]].name;
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(
        g, goal_vertex, //<-- solve to goal 
        get(&VertexProperty::predecessor, g),
        get(&VertexProperty::distance, g),
        get(&EdgeProperty::weight, g),
        identity_property_map(), // index-map
        less<double>(), // compare
        plus<double>(), // combine 
        numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), // infinity
        0.0, // zero
        do_nothing_dijkstra_visitor(),
        get(&VertexProperty::color, g));
    cout << "distances and parents:" << endl;
    // Traverse the vertices from the start to goal,
    //  through the "predecessor" links:
    current_vertex = start_vertex;
    while (current_vertex != goal_vertex) {
        cout << g[current_vertex].name << " " << 
 g[current_vertex].distance;
        current_vertex = g[current_vertex].predecessor;
    };
    cout << g[goal_vertex].name << " " << g[goal_vertex].distance << endl;
    break;
case '2': //do the work for minimum spanning
    break;
case '3': //do the work for travelling salesman
    break;
case 'q':
case 'Q':
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    break;
default:
    goto returnQuestion;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What's the error?  "it freaks out" is about as undescriptive as it gets and completely unhelpful in trying to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Valid point, sorry. The title was the error. its a debug assertion error, stating that the string iterator + offset out of range

Comment: Indent your code, if only to increase your odds of getting help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include these relevant details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file for any empty lines. If your edge filling loop finds an empty line it gives you exactly that error, as you try to erase characters at nonexisting positions.